# Check if Key Structure exists in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to have a function that returns True when a given list of keys lead to an existing structure inside the dictionary. Each key corresponds to the depth level of the dictionary

The struggle that I have is the fact that both the length of the List (= amount of Keys) and the depth of the dictionary are dynamic

```
#Example Code:

keys1 = ["K1", "K3", "K4"]
keys2 = ["K2", "K6"]
keys3 = ["K1", "K6", "K4"]

dict = {
    "K1": {
        "K3": {
            "K4": "a"
        }
    },
    "K2": {
        "K6": "b"
    }
}

result = function(keys1, dict) #result should be True    
result = function(keys2, dict) #result should be True    
result = function(keys3, dict) #result should be False
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you need to write a recursive function which check that each key is inside the previsou key and in this fucntion you pass the keys and new dictionar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple recursive approach:

```
def function(keys, dct):
    return not keys or (keys[0] in dct and function(keys[1:], dct[keys[0]]))

>>> function(keys1, dct)  # never shadow built-in names
True
>>> function(keys2, dct)
True
>>> function(keys3, dct)
False
```

This assumes a quite uniform structure: all intermediate values are dicts themselves and the depth is always at least the length of the keys. Otherwise, you would need to handle some errors:

```
def function(keys, dct):
    try:
        return not keys or function(keys[1:], dct[keys[0]])
    except (TypeError, KeyError):  # this allows you to shorten the above
        return False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a recursive function that traverses the dictionary, checking if the key exists at each level, returning False if it doesn't or True if the list of keys becomes empty.

```py
def function(keys, dictionary):
    if len(keys) == 0:
        return True
    elif keys[0] in dictionary:
        return function(keys[1:], dictionary[keys[0]])
    else:
        return False
```

(As schwobaseggl pointed out in another answer, you shouldn't shadow the built-in name `dict`.)

Answer (score 2):

This loops through all values and checks if the value were working with is a dictionary or not:

```
def function(keys, dictionary):
    for value in keys1:
        if not isinstance(dictionary,dict) or value not in dictionary:
            return False
        dictionary = dictionary[value]
    return True
```

One point: don't name your variables dict, it clashes with the built-in type dict.